# Image Gallery algorithm with parent class inside twig loop

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

Im trying to create an image gallery using twig. Ive done this before. [Here was my initial question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948021/twig-image-gallery-algorithm-for-bootstrap-columns/42951496#42951496) And that gallery works (Almost always), the one I already created is used for Bootstrap if you put the Twig `for each` loop under the parent div, and only loop the `col` classes of bootstrap.

This time arround however, I need to put the parent div inside the `for each` loop. So im trying to make some checks so that the header is only displayed only if it goes to a new row, and so that the items get the correct width (This is in the header).

This is the parent class and as you can see the `columns4` is the tag that gives the child classes their width. So my start was to use the algorithm that ive used already before.

```
 <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns4 flex_allign" id="list">
```

My code at this moment:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        {% setcontent sponsor = "sponsor" %}

        {% set Rest = sponsor|length %}
        {% set Totaal = sponsor|length %}
        {% set TellerLayer = 4 %}
        {% set EndTotaal = 0 %}

        {% for item in sponsor|reverse %}

           {% set EndTotaal = EndTotaal + 1 %}

           {% if (Rest == 4)  %}
           {% if (TellerLayer != 4) %}
                </div>
                <div class="spacer-75"></div>
           {% endif %}
           <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns4 flex_allign" id="list">

           {% elseif (Rest == 3) %}
           </div>
           <div class="spacer-75"></div>
           <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns3 flex_allign" id="list">

           {% elseif (Rest == 2)  %}
           </div>
           <div class="spacer-75"></div>
           <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns2 flex_allign" id="list">

           {% elseif (Rest == 1) %}
           </div>
           <div class="spacer-40"></div>
           <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns1 flex_allign" id="list">

           {% endif %}

       {% set TellerLayer = TellerLayer + 1 %}
       {% set Rest = Rest - 1 %}

            <div class="events people places streets element portfolio_item">
                 <div class="portfolio_item_block">
                        <div class="portfolio_item_wrapper">
                           CONTENT HERE     
                        </div>
                 </div>
               {% if (Totaal == EndTotaal) %}
               </div>
               {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

What this does is, lets say I have 6 items.

- `columns4`, 3 items
- `columns3`, 1 item
- `columns2`, 1 item
- `columns1`, 1 item

And the expected here is:

- `columns4`, 4 items
- `columns2`, 2 items

I hope anyone has any tips on how I can put some more error control in this becouse it just pushes in the headers now before the last header was filled.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Ive added PHP tag becouse twig is practically translated to PHP when it initialisez. so if there is an PHP solution to this it may be good doable in twig.

Comment: Maybe you might want to take a look at the batch filter in twig which could help to simplify your code there and help you identify possible errors more easily https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html

Comment: @Joe Im feeling stupid. ive searched for something like that. but my english is bad so I didnt think about looking for "batch". thank you ill try making my code in this syntax. but also in the syntax I tried in the above question. thanx for pointing it out!

Comment: @Joe Ive created a version using your tip. :D thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more fiddling arround ive fixed it. And I even fixed it in 2 syntaxes.
One thanks to the comment of **Joe**.

Version 1, This one is regarding the own created syntax as seen in the question. 
This one is also a whole lot easier to customize to your own needs.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     {% setcontent sponsor = "sponsor" %}
         {% set Rest = sponsor|length %}
         {% set Totaal = sponsor|length %}
         {% set TellerLayer = 4 %}
         {% set EndTotaal = 0 %}

         {% for item in sponsor|reverse %}
            {% set EndTotaal = EndTotaal + 1 %}

            {% if (Rest >= 4) and (TellerLayer is divisible by(4)) %}
                  {% if (TellerLayer != 4) %}
                  </div>
                  <div class="spacer-75"></div>
                  {% endif %}
            <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns4 flex_allign" id="list">

            {% elseif (Rest == 3) and (TellerLayer is divisible by(4)) %}
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-75"></div>
            <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns3 flex_allign" id="list">

            {% elseif (Rest == 2) and (TellerLayer is divisible by(4)) %}
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-75"></div>
            <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns2 flex_allign" id="list">

            {% elseif (Rest == 1) and (TellerLayer is divisible by(4)) %}
            </div>
            <div class="spacer-40"></div>
            <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns1 flex_allign" id="list">

            {% endif %}

         {% set TellerLayer = TellerLayer + 1 %}
         {% set Rest = Rest - 1 %}

         <div class="events people places streets element portfolio_item">
           CONTENT GOES HERE                                            
         </div>
         {% if (Totaal == EndTotaal) %}
         </div>
         {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Version 2, This one ive created using the comment of **Joe*. Personally I find this one more organized and "Correct syntax". But V1 is easier to customize

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     {% setcontent sponsor = "sponsor" %}
         {% set Totaal = sponsor|length %}
         {% set FoutControle1 = 4 %}
         {% set Variabel = 4 %}

         {% for row in sponsor|reverse|batch(4) %}
            <div class="spacer-75"></div>
            <div class="sorting_block portfolio_block image-grid columns{{ Variabel }} flex_allign" id="list">
                {% for item in row %}
                   <div class="events people places streets element portfolio_item">         Content Goes here
                   </div>
                   {% set Totaal = Totaal - 1 %}
                   {% set FoutControle1 = FoutControle1 + 1 %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
         {% if Totaal >= 4 %}
            {% set Variabel = 4 %}
         {% elseif (Totaal == 3) and (FoutControle1 is divisible by(4)) %}
            {% set Variabel = 3 %}
         {% elseif (Totaal == 2) and (FoutControle1 is divisible by(4)) %}
            {% set Variabel = 2 %}
         {% elseif (Totaal == 1) and (FoutControle1 is divisible by(4)) %}
            {% set Variabel = 1 %}
         {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I hope this helps other people, so far as I know this is the first "working" variable image gallery parse in Twig. So hope this helps!! :)